# How to show the name of the called smart contract function in input data

Tags: ethereum, solidity

I would like to see the name of the called function in the input data like on [this page](https://etherscan.io/tx/0xe7fc310721ce6d6ebb11811aeea191f2a975ddeecec325344778f205e9950bec). I can only achieve this if I use a setter (see below) but I would like to use a custom function name.

```
function set(uint _myHash) public {       
    if (owner == msg.sender) {
        myHash = _myHash;
    }
}

Function: set(uint256 x) ***

MethodID: 0x60fe47b1
[0]:  e4c71652c9fa586fcd99c8b5de545f2dd0b17534bf79c36a47a193dc8aa13c68
```

If I change the name of the setter, my input data will only look like this:

```
0x30096f76c6aa3589e9be255a9cef8981d68902cfac7652a1dfbf7ff9dd0609a6a7ee86ed
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you [verify your code on Etherscan](https://programtheblockchain.com/posts/2018/01/16/verifying-contract-source-code/). If you've provided the source code, Etherscan will show it and automatically decode your transactions.

Comment: Thanks, I was not sure if I have to do that.

Comment: You can show the function name regardless of the verifying contract.

Comment: I still face the issue, how to fix that @Danny?